# File permission problems after migration to iMac

Tags: permission, file, migration-assistant

I used the migration assistant to transfer files from my MacBook Pro (2011) to my iMac. Both computers run Mavericks. Now I'm not allowed to modify files which originate from my 'old' computer because of file permissions. The folders have this red sign and if I look with GetInfo the only authority with read&write access is "fetching".

I don't know whether it is relevant but after migration also the computer name changed from ...iMac to ...MacBook Pro and the transferred files are in a folder which is at the same hierarchy like my home folder of my iMac. Any suggestion how to obtain write access to my transferred files?

Terminal outputs of file properties per Douggro's request:

```
mac-Myname:~ iMacMyname$ ls -l /Users/iMacMyname/Desktop
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  7 iMacMyname  staff  238 Jul 10  2013 Universal
```

```
mac-Myname:~ iMacMyname$ ls -l /Users/MacBookMyname/Desktop
ls: Desktop: Permission denied`
```

Comment: Have you tried repairing permissions with Disk Utility? Where (what directory) are the problem files located? Open Terminal and type `ls -l` and drag a problem file into the Terminal window and press Return. Do the same with a good file and edit your question with the output. That will show the ownership/permissions and provide a basis for getting more helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Yes, I tried using Disk Utility to repair it, but had it had no effect.  The output I get, following your instructions are: mac-Myname:~ iMacMyname$ ls -l /Users/iMacMyname/Desktop 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  7 iMacMyname  staff  238 Jul 10  2013 Universal
mac-Myname:~ iMacMyname$ ls -l /Users/MacBookMyname/Desktop
ls: Desktop: Permission denied

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to access files that are in a different User account. For whatever reason, Migration Assistant imported your MacBook files as a separate user. You could try running the Assistant again and carefully select your options during the configuration. You should be able to migrate the files and settings even though the usernames on the two computers are different.

Comment: @douggro Thanks for editing and the answer. I will try to rerun the migration assistant. Nevertheless since my MacBook Pro has some hardware problems and is unstable, is there a way to move the data to my iMac user account and delete then the additional one?

Comment: Ah and I forgot: There is no additional user at the login screen. It seems only an additional user folder is created.

Comment: Odd that it moved the data into another User folder without creating the account. Migration Assistant is your best bet to get all the files, apps and settings moved. If you could get the MBP booted in Target Disk Mode or get the hard drive out and mounted on the iMac, that would be another way to use MA. There are some ways to copy and change the ownership of the files in Terminal using `sudo cp` and `sudo chown` but that's fraught with some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a fix!

Basically "Get Info" then at the bottom of the window next to the gear icon click on the + button. In the next window choose your account name. It creates a new permission category. then just choose Read & Write and apply to all enclosed. I have just done this to 3 machines. It's magic!! and after 3 hours of frustration.